# What is meant by 'The components of a force along a given axis'?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, vectors, coordinate-systems

I'm new to mechanics, and I'm having trouble interpreting what this means. So there's a force, okay. Then it has its components on the xyz axis, okay. But what does it mean by along a given axis, I thought it was the xyz axis. I'm so confused.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Say you know a force of magnitude $F_a$ acts along the direction $\hat{a}$

The force vector is thus $$\vec{F} = F_a\, \hat{a}$$

In reverse, to find out the magnitude, you can use the dot product

$$ F_a = \vec{F} \cdot \hat{a} \tag{1}$$

If $F_a$ is positive, then there are parts of $\vec{F}$ that are along $\hat{a}$, if $F_a$ is negative, then there are parts of $\vec{F}$ that are along $-\hat{a}$ and if $F_a$ is zero, then $\vec{F}$ is perpendicular to $\hat{a}$.

If you can do this for the direction $\hat{a}$ you can also do it for a different direction $\hat{b}$

$$ F_b = \vec{F} \cdot \hat{b} \tag{2}$$

and similarly for infinite other directions

$$ F_c = \vec{F} \cdot \hat{c} \tag{3}$$
$$ F_d = \vec{F} \cdot \hat{d} $$
$$ \cdots $$

Now for a 3D problem, you need three components to fully describe any vector $\vec{F}$ such that

$$ \vec{F} = F_a \hat{a} + F_b \hat{b} + F_c \hat{c} \tag{4}$$

It does not matter if the 3 directions are perpendicular to each other, as long as they are *not* parallel and are unit vectors. If those conditions are met then we call $ \{ \hat{a}, \hat{b}, \hat{c} \}$ the basis vectors used.

The most common basis vectors are the three axes *x*, *y*, and *z*.

In summary, use (1), (2), (3) to find the components of any vector as shown in (4)

<sub>Note that in 2D space, you only need 2 basis vectors.</sub>

In case one of the basis vectors *is not* a unit vector, such as $\vec{a}$ then you can make it a unit vector with $$ \hat{a} = { \vec{a} \over \| \vec{a} \| }$$

So to find the component of vector $\vec{F}$ along another vector $\vec{a}$ you would do

$$ F_a =\frac{ \vec{F} \cdot \vec{a} } { \| \vec{a} \|} $$

And considering the closing of the angle between the two vectors is defined as $$ \cos \theta = \frac{F_a}{\| \vec{F} \|} = \frac{ \vec{F} \cdot \vec{a} } { \| \vec{a} \| \| \vec{F} \|} $$

Answer (score 1):

On the left hand side I have defined three unit vectors $\hat p,\,\hat q$ and $\hat q_\perp$ the first two of which correspond in direction to vectors $\vec{OB}= \underline{Q}$ and $\vec{OA}= \underline{P}$.

[image]

Your vector $\underline P = P \,\hat p$ where in this case $P$ is the magnitude of the vector $\underline P$ and $\hat p$ is its direction.

Now the vector $\underline P$ can be split into components along the $\hat q$ direction and the $\hat q_\perp$ direction such that $$\underline P = P\, \hat p = P\,\cos \theta \,\hat q + P\,\sin\theta \,\hat q_\perp$$

as shown in the diagram on the right.

So rather than use the words *along a given axis* I have used the words *in a given direction*.

In terms of the $x$ and $y$ axes I could have chosen my unit vectors to be along (parallel to) unit vectors $\hat q$ and $\hat q_\perp$, and labelled them $\hat x$ and $\hat y$, or $\hat i$ and $\hat j$.

What the dot product does for you is that it enables you to find the component of a vector in a given direction (along a given axis).

In your case $\underline P \cdot \hat q= (P\,\cos \theta \,\hat q + P\,\sin\theta \,\hat q_\perp)\cdot \hat q= P\,\cos \theta$ as $\hat q \cdot \hat q = 1$ and $\hat q \cdot \hat q_\perp = 0$

Answer (score -1):

I believe force vector is a two dimensional quantity, so it is $x$ and $y$ axes. The image says component of $P$ along $Q$ direction, I believe that should be the fraction of force $P$ in the $Q$ direction: $Pcos\theta$ as written. Try reading a physics textbook on vectors, that should provide more clarity.